# Raspbian enable SPI module

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

sorry if this is not the right forum for this question but I
can't find the answer anywhere.  I'm working on a raspberry pi project
which requires the SPI module to be loaded.  I can't get it to load.
Here's what I've done

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo rpi-update
```

Here's what my blacklist.conf file looks like

```
#blacklist spi and i2c by default (many users don't need them)
#blacklist spi-bcm2708
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

I've rebooted several times with no luck.  When I run `sudo uname -a` I get

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.5+ #744 PREEMPT Fri Jan 30 18:19:07 GMT2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=97314
Fixed my i2c and one-wire interfaces.
This is required with the new kernal upgrade to 3.18.5 on Jan 21st.

Answer (score 1):

You should have it enabled. You did not specify how you test if it works.

What I suggest

- Check if you have it enabled using `lsmod | grep spi_` or `ls -al /dev/spi*`
- If it does not work in your program try `sudo adduser pi spi` (if you use the pi user)
- a) Download http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c
  b) compile it with `gcc spidev_test.c -o spidev_test`. If you get compilation error try downloading this file and compiling it: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c?id=95b1ed2ac7ffe3205afc6f5a20320fbdb984da92 (it is older version of this file)
  c) shorten your MOSI and MISO pins on your Raspberry ( http://neophob.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/254px-GPIOs.png pins 9 and 10 on this schematics, but please double check what pins you should shorten on schematics for your raspberry)
  d) run the compiled program `sudo ./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev0.0`
  e) if it returns
  `FF FF FF FF FF FF 
  40 00 00 00 00 95 
  FF FF FF FF FF FF 
  FF FF FF FF FF FF 
  FF FF FF FF FF FF 
  DE AD BE EF BA AD 
  F0 0D`
  it works and you might have some issue with your program or with connection to some other device.